# Best way to handle direction change in geofence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, location, geofencing

I've a few points on map: A, B, C etc (hundreds of points).
while I'm driving from point A my function tells me that point B is the closest, so what i'm doing is registering a geofence to point B and reduce the accuracy to 3 kilometer in CLLocationManager.
On the way, the driver decided to drive to point C.

My questions are:

1. How should I know the driver is on his way to different point and then cancel the geofence and register a new one?
2. The accuracy of 3 kilometer is good enough to save battery or should I use significantLocationChanges or should I turn off the GPS?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I should have been clear, my app is a speed trap app.
A speed trap can be with 2 sides on the same road, and the driver can always make a u-tern while he is in the radius of the geofence (the speed trap radius).

Comment: You do have 20 regions to play with, can you not register all of the 20 closest? Will you have more than 20 within 3km? You can also set a region around your current location so you get notified when the user leaves that region...

Comment: But what about the battery usage? No more then 20 for sure in 3 kilometer.

Comment: Using only regions is best from a battery point of view.

Comment: Yes, but 20 regions all the time? There must be a perfect combination between regions and direction change, right?

Comment: Do you need any updates other than when you leave / get to a location? Otherwise all you need is regions...

Comment: Between point A to B, I don't need the location. But let me be clear, this is a speed trap app, and if the driver make a u-tern or if there's are speed trap with cameras for north and south way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44879/discussion-between-wain-and-idan-moshe)